# Как прокинуть React props в mui select с кастомной стилизацией?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Я использую React и Mui Select, который имеет кастомные стили. Я не понимаю, как мне перекинуть пропсы в эти стили. В этом примере я прокидываю в компонент MuiSelect параметр height, который по умолчанию равен 32px. Select использует параметр sx={styles}. Мне нужно вставить height в виде переменной в объекте styles. Как это сделать?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select, {SelectChangeEvent} from '@mui/material/Select';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

const options = [
  {id: '1', value: 'One'},
  {id: '2', value: 'Two'},
  {id: '3', value: 'Three'},
  {id: '4', value: 'Four'},
]

const styles = {
  width: '100%',
  border: '1px solid #D9D9D9',
  borderRadius: '16px',
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 700,
  fontSize: '14px',
  color: '#5E5E5E',
  
  height: '40px',
}

interface IProps {
  height?: string;
}

const MuiSelect: React.FC<IProps> = ({height = '32px'}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('One');

  const handleChange = (e: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
      <Select
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        sx={styles}
      >
        {
          options.map(item => 
            <MenuItem 
              key={item.id} 
              value={item.value}
            >
              {item.value}
            </MenuItem>)
        }
      </Select>

  );
}

export default MuiSelect;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
const styles = (height) => {
  width: '100%',
  border: '1px solid #D9D9D9',
  borderRadius: '16px',
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 700,
  fontSize: '14px',
  color: '#5E5E5E',
  
  height,
}

....

<Select
     value={value}
     onChange={handleChange}
     sx={() => styles(height)}
>
```

Вероятно стоит обернуть в useMemo, если планируется много ререндеров, чтоб не возвращать это несколько раз без изменения аргумента height